# y tick labels on matplotlib subplots with sharey=True

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

Using matplotlib subplots I would like to have the common ylabels for dataframes that do not have the same index. But the [default behaviour](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) of subplots is to use the labels of the first column.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'values':[2,3,5]},index=['a','b','c'])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'values':[1,1,1]},index=['a','b','d'])

_,a=plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=1,sharey=True,sharex=True)
df1.plot(kind='barh',ax=a[0],legend=False)
df2.plot(kind='barh',ax=a[1],legend=False)
```

this code will show a subplot where the value 'c' is labeled as 'd'.

The only way around I can think is to concatenate the dataframes creating a common index.

```
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,sort=False)
df3.columns=['df1','df2']
_,a=plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=1,sharey=True,sharex=True)
df3.df1.plot(kind='barh',legend=False,ax=a[0])
df3.df2.plot(kind='barh',legend=False,ax=a[1])
```

Is there a more elegant solution ?

Comment: You are sharing the y axis. So if that is required, the solution you found or the one from the answer below are the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reindex with the union of the indexes from your two dataframes before plotting

```
new_index = df1.index.union(df2.index)
df1 = df1.reindex(new_index)
df2 = df2.reindex(new_index)

_,a=plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=1,sharex=True)
df1.plot(kind='barh',ax=a[0],legend=False)
df2.plot(kind='barh',ax=a[1],legend=False)
```